# Why does event bubbling not work when using css grid with elements occupying the same cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, css-grid

I have two grid children that occupy the same cell. They both have `click` event listeners. According to [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events), both event listeners should be fired when I click on the cell.

```js
const outer = document.getElementById('outer')
outer.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('on outer click'))

const inner1 = document.getElementById('inner1')
inner1.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('on inner1 click'))

const inner2 = document.getElementById('inner2')
inner2.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('on inner2 click'))
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
}

#inner2 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

#inner1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner1">

  </div>
  <div id="inner2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/o10sfpwu/

Expected log:

```
on inner2 click
on inner1 click
on outer click
```

Actual log:

```
on inner2 click
on outer click
```

Why is the inner1 event listener not fired? The click event should bubble through all elements occupying this space, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The click event should bubble through all elements occupying this space, right?

The click event (or any event) will only bubble through the *DOM ancestors* of an element. The position of the element is not considered, nor is whether the position overlaps with another element while an event is bubbling.

In this case, because the `inner2` is at the same cell as `inner1`, and `inner2` is put after `inner1` in the DOM, the `inner2` will be on top of the `inner1`. So, clicking on that cell results in an event being dispatched to the `inner2`. Then, to see which other elements see the event while bubbling, look at `inner2`'s ancestors:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner1">

  </div>
  <div id="inner2">

  </div>
</div>
```

But its ancestors are only `#outer` (and the `document.body`, and the `document.documentElement`). `inner1` is not an ancestor, and the event was dispatched to `inner2`, so the event does not bubble through `inner1`.

This is described in [your MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events):

> In the bubbling phase:
>
> - The browser checks to see if the element that was actually clicked on has an onclick event handler registered on it in the bubbling phase, and runs it if so.
> - Then it moves on to the **next immediate ancestor element** and does the same thing, then the next one, and so on until it reaches the  element.

Comment: This is clear, thanks. If I want events to bubble to both inner1 and inner2, my only option is to make them descendents of each other, right?

Comment: If it would *make sense* for one element to be a descendant of the other, sure. It would result in both elements seeing the event.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer already answers correctly your question, I'll just abuse the answer form to point you (and possible future readers) to [document.elementsFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementsFromPoint) which I think is actually what you wanted:

```js
const outer = document.getElementById('outer')
outer.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  const nodes = document.elementsFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
  nodes.forEach( (node) => console.log( 'clicked over', node));
});
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
}

#inner2 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

#inner1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner1">

  </div>
  <div id="inner2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is kinda tricky with react.js etc though because children don't know who their parents are